# Oracle Database: SQL Query have different behavior in different environment

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to execute the following SQL query in two 'Oracle SQL Developer'. each in different environment (local/client).

The Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM myTable t
WHERE (:P_STATUS = -1 OR t.STATUS = :P_STATUS);
```

The Parameter:
 `P_STATUS = -1 'Integer'` (to display all data in the table)

The expected result: 
 All records in the table displayed

The result:
 Local: All records in the table displayed
 Client: No record in the table displayed

Note:
1- The problem didn't occur in the following queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM myTable t
WHERE :P_STATUS = -1) ;
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM myTable t
WHERE (:P_STATUS = -1 OR 1=2);
```

2- It already executed well in client yesterday but today it gives this strange behavior. so i think that there is a changed configuration but I can not expect it or find any similar issue in google.

3- The query also executed well when i select specific status (:P_STATUS = 2).

Update:
The query run correct if I select from the table but when select from a view on table, it returns no data.

Also run correct in Toad and not run correct in SQL Developer.

Problem in status datatype. In table number (2) and also in view
But following query makes it run on SQL Developer

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM myTable t
WHERE (:P_STATUS = -1 OR to_number(t.STATUS) = :P_STATUS);
```

Comment: Are both the client and local connecting to the same database? Are they both connecting to the same user (`SELECT USER FROM DUAL`) and tablespace (`SELECT table_name, tablespace_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'`)? If you do `DESCRIBE myTable;` from both do they have the same descriptions?

Answer (score 0):

If the data has been `INSERT`ed from a session on the local machine but has not been `COMMIT`ted then it will only be visible (in its uncommitted state) from within that session. Trying to `SELECT` the data from another session (i.e. the client) will not show any results.

To solve this, `COMMIT` the data in the local session.

Comment: Data already committed and the table returns data if i enter a different status (ex:  P_STATUS = 2).